# Why does viewport unit sizing change when Bootstrap isn't loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

**The same element(set to height:100vh) in the same window showing the website page, before and after deleting the `import` line reports different client height: 881 with the import, 914 without the import**

I added bootstrap to the project a long time ago and never ended up using any of the actual elements provided, so i deleted the npm file and the `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Somehow that changed the vh and vmin values such that the app body has stretched and the page began showing the scrollbar, as well as the font-sizing function (which works with fudges my vmin-dependent font sizes) has begun going haywire

Before deleting the

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

> [image: Before deleting the line][image: After deleting the line]

The app consists of a single page which is supposed to fit the window exactly and a grid of widgets and images, everything scaling off of the window size through vmin or vh or vw.

Changing this one line, which is the only trace of Bootstrap in my project, has really upended the internal workings. I am wondering what happened, what was the bootstrap.min.css adding to the project and can i manually put it back in without carrying the whole library with me

Minimal code example:

App.js

```
import './App.css';

/* import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  */ 

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
        <div className="App-body" id='body'>
          Hi
         </div>
    </div>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0%;
}


.App-body {
  background-color: #3c4558;
  display: grid;
  grid: 5.9% 12.6% 3.7% 9.8% 11.7% 17.5% 7.3% 22.4% / 15% 10% 22% 22% 23.5%;
  padding: 1.3%;
  gap: 1.3%;
  margin: 0%;
  height: 100vh;/*this is REALLY weird*/
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: _"Somehow that changed the vh and vmin values"_ - no, it didn't, because it _can't_. Those are coming from the viewport. _"such that the app body has stretched and the page began showing the scrollbar"_ - body gets a default margin of (usually) 8px applied from the user agent stylesheet - and 100% + x is always > 100%, if the x is > 0. Bootstrap comes with a "CSS reset" portion, that eliminates this default body margin. So in case you applied 100vh to body's height, you will have to eliminate that default margin yourself now.

Comment: _"Can it be anything else?"_ - sure, but there is currently no way for us to tell what it might be in this specific instance. We'd need a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: But if you used your browser dev tools and inspected the elements in question, you should probably be able to figure this out yourself, if you compare both versions carefully ...

Comment: Whether padding gets added to height, or included in it, gets controlled via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like an issue with `box-sizing` which defines whether padding is *included* in `height` and `width` values or *added* to them.

Try to add `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` which includes padding in these values for *all* elements.

Comment: Please clean up redundant comment-answers and all related meta-discussion comments.